# chartjs datapoints breakes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

[image: graf break]
I don't know If I have done anything wrong or if this is just an annoying bug.

I want to be able to have two charts on top of each other and have the 24-hour format
so the x-axis should start from 0 and go to 23:59

When I add one datapoint to the chart it works and it does not break. As soon as I add another datapoint it breaks.
If you look at the image the `Monthly totals` works, but as soon as I get the `data2 info` then some data points on the red line just start to break.

Also I don't know how to remove some of the labels since there are duplicates

[Codesandbox link to bug](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-gagarin-ocdnv8?file=/src/App.js)

This is how my datapoints are

```
let dailyGeneration = [
    { x: "00:01:00", y: 1 },
    { x: "00:10:00", y: 8 },
    { x: "00:16:00", y: 9 },
    { x: "00:21:00", y: 4 },
    { x: "00:53:00", y: 8 },
    { x: "01:01:00", y: 2 },
    { x: "01:03:10", y: 5 },
    { x: "01:11:01", y: 4 },
    { x: "01:21:20", y: 1 },
    { x: "02:12:00", y: 4 },
    { x: "03:00:00", y: 1 },
    { x: "04:00:00", y: 6 },
    { x: "05:00:00", y: 5 },
    { x: "06:00:00", y: 5 },
    { x: "07:00:00", y: 3 },
    { x: "08:00:00", y: 8 },
    { x: "09:00:00", y: 9 },
    { x: "10:00:00", y: 1 },
    { x: "11:00:00", y: 2 },
    { x: "12:00:00", y: 1.6 },
    { x: "13:00:00", y: 2.6 },
    { x: "14:00:00", y: 5.4 },
    { x: "15:00:00", y: 7.6 },
    { x: "16:00:00", y: 1.6 },
    { x: "16:01:00", y: 2.6 },
    { x: "16:20:00", y: 1.1 },
    { x: "17:00:00", y: 2.3 },
    { x: "18:00:00", y: 1.9 },
    { x: "19:00:00", y: 0.7 },
    { x: "20:00:00", y: 6 },
    { x: "21:00:00", y: 8 },
    { x: "22:00:00", y: 9 },
    { x: "23:00:00", y: 3.5 },
  ];
```

```
let montlyTotals = [
    { x: "00:01", y: 9 },
    { x: "01:00", y: 8 },
    { x: "02:00", y: 5 },
    { x: "03:00", y: 2.5 },
    { x: "04:00", y: 1.7 },
    { x: "05:00", y: 9.3 },
    { x: "06:00", y: 2.4 },
    { x: "07:00", y: 4.3 },
    { x: "08:00", y: 5.4 },
    { x: "09:00", y: 7.6 },
    { x: "10:00", y: 6.3 },
    { x: "11:00", y: 1.3 },
    { x: "12:00", y: 2.6 },
    { x: "13:00", y: 4.3 },
    { x: "14:00", y: 2.1 },
    { x: "15:00", y: 1.6 },
    { x: "16:00", y: 6 },
    { x: "17:00", y: 4 },
    { x: "18:00", y: 1 },
    { x: "19:00", y: 4.2 },
    { x: "20:00", y: 6.32 },
    { x: "21:00", y: 8.2 },
    { x: "22:00", y: 2.5 },
    { x: "23:00", y: 1.1 },
  ];
```

```
let yourData = {
    datasets: [
      {
        type: "line",
        label: "Daily Generation",
        data: usageData,
        borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1)",
        xAxisID: "daily-x-axis",
        yAxisID: "daily-y-axis",
      },
      {
        type: "line",
        label: "Monthly Totals",
        data: montlyTotals,
        borderColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",
        xAxisID: "monthly-x-axis",
        yAxisID: "monthly-y-axis",
      },
    ],
  };

  const yourOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: "top" as const,
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Chart.js Line Chart",
      },
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        "daily-x-axis": {
          type: "time",
          time: {
            unit: "hour",
            displayFormats: {
              day: "MMM DD, YYYY",
              month: "MMM",
            },
            tooltipFormat: "dddd, MMM DD, YYYY",
          },
          ticks: {
            minRotation: 80,
            maxRotation: 90,
            color: "blue",
          },
          position: "bottom",
        },
        "monthly-x-axis": {
          type: "time",
          time: {
            unit: "hour",
            displayFormats: {
              day: "MMM DD, YYYY",
              month: "MMM",
            },
            tooltipFormat: "MMM, YYYY",
          },
          ticks: {
            color: "green",
          },
          position: "bottom",
        },
        "daily-y-axis": {
          position: "left",
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "kWh / day",
            color: "blue",
          },
          ticks: {
            color: "blue",
          },
        },
        "monthly-y-axis": {
          position: "right",
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "total kWh / month",
            color: "green",
          },
          ticks: {
            color: "green",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFA I see, there is a bug in the chart configuration. The `options` node it's wrong and it must be removed. This is the reason of the bug and why the scales are not what your are defining (see missing colors and correct position in your picture) and is using the defaults (`linear` ones).

```js
let dailyGeneration = [
    { x: "00:01:00", y: 1 },
    { x: "00:10:00", y: 8 },
    { x: "00:16:00", y: 9 },
    { x: "00:21:00", y: 4 },
    { x: "00:53:00", y: 8 },
    { x: "01:01:00", y: 2 },
    { x: "01:03:10", y: 5 },
    { x: "01:11:01", y: 4 },
    { x: "01:21:20", y: 1 },
    { x: "02:12:00", y: 4 },
    { x: "03:00:00", y: 1 },
    { x: "04:00:00", y: 6 },
    { x: "05:00:00", y: 5 },
    { x: "06:00:00", y: 5 },
    { x: "07:00:00", y: 3 },
    { x: "08:00:00", y: 8 },
    { x: "09:00:00", y: 9 },
    { x: "10:00:00", y: 1 },
    { x: "11:00:00", y: 2 },
    { x: "12:00:00", y: 1.6 },
    { x: "13:00:00", y: 2.6 },
    { x: "14:00:00", y: 5.4 },
    { x: "15:00:00", y: 7.6 },
    { x: "16:00:00", y: 1.6 },
    { x: "16:01:00", y: 2.6 },
    { x: "16:20:00", y: 1.1 },
    { x: "17:00:00", y: 2.3 },
    { x: "18:00:00", y: 1.9 },
    { x: "19:00:00", y: 0.7 },
    { x: "20:00:00", y: 6 },
    { x: "21:00:00", y: 8 },
    { x: "22:00:00", y: 9 },
    { x: "23:00:00", y: 3.5 },
  ];
let montlyTotals = [
    { x: "00:01", y: 9 },
    { x: "01:00", y: 8 },
    { x: "02:00", y: 5 },
    { x: "03:00", y: 2.5 },
    { x: "04:00", y: 1.7 },
    { x: "05:00", y: 9.3 },
    { x: "06:00", y: 2.4 },
    { x: "07:00", y: 4.3 },
    { x: "08:00", y: 5.4 },
    { x: "09:00", y: 7.6 },
    { x: "10:00", y: 6.3 },
    { x: "11:00", y: 1.3 },
    { x: "12:00", y: 2.6 },
    { x: "13:00", y: 4.3 },
    { x: "14:00", y: 2.1 },
    { x: "15:00", y: 1.6 },
    { x: "16:00", y: 6 },
    { x: "17:00", y: 4 },
    { x: "18:00", y: 1 },
    { x: "19:00", y: 4.2 },
    { x: "20:00", y: 6.32 },
    { x: "21:00", y: 8.2 },
    { x: "22:00", y: 2.5 },
    { x: "23:00", y: 1.1 },
  ];
let dsMonthly = {
        type: "line",
        label: "Monthly Totals",
        data: montlyTotals,
        borderColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",
        xAxisID: "monthly-x-axis",
        yAxisID: "monthly-y-axis",
      };
let yourData = {
    datasets: [
      {
        type: "line",
        label: "Daily Generation",
        data: dailyGeneration,
        borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1)",
        xAxisID: "daily-x-axis",
        yAxisID: "daily-y-axis",
      }
    ],
  };

  const yourOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: "top",
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Chart.js Line Chart",
        },
      },
      scales: {
        "daily-x-axis": {
          type: "time",
          time: {
            unit: "hour",
            displayFormats: {
              hour: "HH:mm",
            },
            tooltipFormat: "dddd, MMM DD, YYYY",
          },
          ticks: {
            minRotation: 80,
            maxRotation: 90,
            color: "blue",
          },
          position: "bottom",
        },
        "monthly-x-axis": {
          type: "time",
          time: {
            unit: "hour",
            displayFormats: {
              hour: "HH:mm"
            },
            tooltipFormat: "MMM, YYYY",
          },
          ticks: {
            color: "green",
          },
          position: "bottom",
        },
        "daily-y-axis": {
          position: "left",
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "kWh / day",
            color: "blue",
          },
          ticks: {
            color: "blue",
          },
        },
        "monthly-y-axis": {
          position: "right",
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "total kWh / month",
            color: "green",
          },
          ticks: {
            color: "green",
          },
        },
      },
  };
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: yourData,
  options: yourOptions
});

document.getElementById('month').addEventListener('click', function() {
  myChart.data.datasets.push(dsMonthly);
  myChart.update();
  document.getElementById('month').disabled = true;
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.0.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@1.2.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-luxon.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
    <button id="month">Add month dataset</button> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The thing is that if I don't have the options key it will start complaining that `time` is not a scale. I have updated my questions with a codesandbox link

Comment: that show the bug

Comment: @Cyrus Zei as I wrote, the config of the chart is wrong, because "options" must be removed. Furthermore in your sandbox you don't have "TimeScale" is not registered. In my sandbox, forked from yours, I've also added the parser options to parse the hours. See here that it works : https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-haze-x6sy6t

Comment: ahhh, now I see. after a couple of hours you get `blind`. Thank you so much for this